# Gluon JavaFX Rest client

Tags: gluon

I have two questions regarding gluen development:

1) Could I use external jars (`httpclient`, `log4j`, etc.) when I want to develop multi platform (desktop, android, iOS) apps?

2) If not, how can I change request header in `RestClient` (Gluon connect)?

Answer (score 0):

You can. Currently the only non-supported feature is Java 8 streams, so you want to avoid those in your code and libraries

Comment: With respect to Java 8 streams: Alternatively the [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) library could be used which provides an API that comes quite close to the original.